# Renaming a set of files to 001, 002,

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, rename

I originally had a set of images of the form image_001.jpg, image_002.jpg, ...

I went through them and removed several. Now I'd like to rename the leftover files back to image_001.jpg, image_002.jpg, ...

Is there a Linux command that will do this neatly? I'm familiar with rename but can't see anything to order file names like this. I'm thinking that since `ls *.jpg` lists the files in order (with gaps), the solution would be to pass the output of that into a bash loop or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand right, you have e.g. image_001.jpg, image_003.jpg, image_005.jpg, and you want to rename to image_001.jpg, image_002.jpg, image_003.jpg.

EDIT: This is modified to put the temp file in the current directory.  As Stephan202 noted, this can make a significant difference if temp is on a different filesystem.  To avoid hitting the temp file in the loop, it now goes through image*

```
i=1; temp=$(mktemp -p .); for file in image*
do
mv "$file" $temp;
mv $temp $(printf "image_%0.3d.jpg" $i)
i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: Nice (as long as mktemp creates a file on the same volume, otherwise moving to a temporary subdirectory is faster)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, but I didn't need to use a temp directory: my images actually started at 002 (with gaps), therefore there couldn't be any conflicts. 002 is renamed 001, 005->002, 006->003 and so on.

Comment: For other people's reference, my final command was: i=0; for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" $(printf "image_%0.3d.jpg" $i); i=$((i+1)); done

Answer (score 9):

A simple loop (test with `echo`, execute with `mv`):

```
I=1
for F in *; do
  echo "$F" `printf image_%03d.jpg $I`
  #mv "$F" `printf image_%03d.jpg $I` 2>/dev/null || true
  I=$((I + 1))
done
```

(I added `2>/dev/null || true` to suppress warnings about identical source and target files. If this is not to your liking, go with [Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47773/matthew-flaschen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880467/renaming-a-set-of-files-to-001-002-on-linux/880488#880488).)

Comment: This doesn't work.  Most of the images will still have their original names, so the mv will fail.

Comment: @Matthew: good spot. Now changed the code so that all files are moved to a temporary directory.

Comment: To be clear, it will work on the other images, but will produce spurious errors that can break e.g. Makefiles.

Comment: @Matthew: on second thought, failing is not a problem. I'll revert the code.

Comment: Keep in mind, mv fails even with the /dev/null, so make (and similar) still break.

Comment: Doh. I should go to bed. Anyway, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Some good answers here already; but some rely on hiding errors which is not a good idea (that assumes `mv` will only error because of a condition that is expected - what about all the other reaons `mv` might error?).

Moreover, it can be done a little shorter and should be better quoted:

```
for file in *; do
    printf -vsequenceImage 'image_%03d.jpg' "$((++i))"
    [[ -e $sequenceImage ]] || \
        mv "$file" "$sequenceImage"
done
```

Also note that [you shouldn't capitalize your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization/673940#673940) in bash scripts.

Comment: With recent versions of bash you can use:

printf -vsequenceImage 'image_%03d.jpg' $((++i))

Comment: Actually, you're manipulating the i variable in a subshell, so in your example it does not get incremented.

Comment: radoulov: well spotted, thanks.  I recon I should test what I write.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script:

[numerate.sh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numerate/files/numerate.sh/download)

This code snipped should do the job:

```
./numerate.sh -d <your image folder> -b <start number> -L 3 -p image_ -s .jpg -o numerically -r
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the reverse of what you are asking (taking files of the form *.jpg.001 and converting them to *.001.jpg), but can easily be modified for your purpose:

```
for file in * 

do

if [[ "$file" =~ "(.*)\.([[:alpha:]]+)\.([[:digit:]]{3,})$" ]]

then

mv "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest something like the above using a for loop, an iterator, cut -f1 -d "_", then mv i i.iterator. It looks like it's already covered other ways, though.