# Renaming a set of files to 001, 002, … php

Tags: php, image, file, rename

I have a set of images in a folder call 'uploads/', all the files are in this form 5f0f905706.jpg, 15758df106.jpg, ...

I want to rename them as is, 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg ...

how i code this?
thanks

Comment: It's uncanny how identical this question is to one I asked a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880467/renaming-a-set-of-files-to-001-002-on-linux (though technically not a dupe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$files = glob("*.jpg");
$num=count($files);
$i=1;
foreach ( $files as $filename) {
    $n=str_pad($i, $num ,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $newfile = $n.".jpg";
    rename($filename,$newfile);
    $i+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

glob(), foreach(), str_pad(), rename()

Answer (score 1):

like

```
 foreach(glob("uploads/*jpg") as $n => $file) {
    $new = dirname($file) . '/' . sprintf("%04d", $n + 1) . '.jpg';
    rename($file, $new);
 }
```