# Changing filename in ubuntu for 001,002

Tags: ubuntu, command, filenames

I'm currently have ~4500 file 2MB with .001, .002 .

I want to remove 2 parts first and 2 parts last (mean remove 001,002 and two last parts

Now I have file from .003, .004

How can I change 003 to 001, 004 to 002, 005 to 003?

Answer (score 0):

It's no pretty solution, but what about something like this?

```
i=1; temp=$(mktemp temp); for file in .[0-9][0-9][0-9]
do
mv "$file" $temp;
mv $temp $(printf ".%0.3d" $i)
i=$((i + 1))    
done
```

(Adapted version of [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

[numerate.sh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numerate/files/numerate.sh/download)

This code snipped should do the job:

```
./numerate.sh -d <your image folder> -b 1 -L 3 -p "." -o numerically -r
```