# Is there any smart way to rename multiple files on terminal with SVN command?

Tags: svn, terminal, file-rename

I have many files to move and rename that's under SVN. The naming rule is below.

```
current path: /root/parent/child_01.html
new path:     /root/parent/child/article_01.html
```

I know I can rename with "svn move" command but I have about 50 files to rename with sequential numbers.

I found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers). It's very similar to my question but I want to do it with files that's under SVN.

Comment: Which OS (i.e command-interpreter used)?

Comment: So the general naming rule is `s{(\w*)_(\d*)\.html}{$1/article_$2.html}`?

Comment: I use Mac OS 10.8.5.
Thank you so much for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern would be the same as for the answers to [the question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211595/2936460):

1. Find all files
2. Craft command
3. Execute command

For your specific situation, this would be something like:

```
find /tmp -regex ".*_\d+\.html$" -regextype posix-extended -type f -print0 | # find all html files with a number in the name
gawk 'BEGIN{ f = gensub(/(.*)(_\d+\.html)/, "\\1/article\\2", "g"); printf "svn mv %s %s\n", $0, f}' | # build svn command
bash # run command
```

**NB**: As a general warning, test scripts like this first by echoing instead of executing. I have not tested this as I don't have a shell at hand.

Comment: And now try to "translate" it into cmd.exe

Comment: @LazyBadger That's left as an exercise for the reader. The forward slashes indicated a Unix-like environment. Also, the linked question that was "very similar" used bash. But cmd should be doable.

Comment: *not easy* without find and gawk

Comment: _Doable_, not necessarily _easy_.