# Linux rename multiple files with a bash script + adding a suffix

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I mention that I've already checked similar questions about renaming files with bash script, but none has helped me with this problem.

I need to rename many files in a directory after the following rule: list the current files alphabetically, then replace their name with a given basic name, add a suffix which is the current file index and then add a given extension.

I encountered a problem at indexing the files. For instance, if I had 1000 files, after executing the script their names should be `file0001.ext, file0002.ext ... file0010.ext ... file0099.ext ... file 0100.ext ... file0999.ext, file1000.ext`.

I've computed the needed number of zeros for every file, but I do not know how to implement the rule with a regular expression within the mv commnad.  Below is my script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

nod=0

i=1
nof=$(ls -v $3 | wc -l)
cpy=$nof
while [ $cpy -gt 0]
do
    nod=$((nod+1))
    cpy=$((cpy/10))
done
for a in $(ls -v $3)
do
    cpy_of_i=$i
    i_digits=0
    while [ $cpy_of_i -gt 0 ]
    do
        i_digits=$((i_digits+1))
        cpy_of_i=$((cpy_of_i/10))
    done
    nr_zeros=$((nod-i_digits))
    old=$3$a
    new=$(echo $3$1[0]\*{nr_zeros}$i.$2)
    mv $old $new
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Note: first argument is the new file name, the second argument is the new extension and the third argument is the directory which contains the files  which are to be renamed. So the script will be called from command line with a command similar to this: `./rename.sh new_file pdf /home/dir/something/`

Comment: I'd start by putting that script into http://shellcheck.net as it's littered with things that would be picked up there. I guess that what you're really looking for is something like `printf '%04d' "$i"` though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep a counter in a variable, use arithmetic expression to increment it after processing each file. Use command substitution with `printf` to create the zero padded number.

```
new=$1
ext=$2
dir=$3

id=1
for file in "$dir"/* ; do
    mv "$file" "$dir/$new"$(printf '%04d' $id)."$ext"
    (( id++ ))
done
```

You might need to only rename `"$dir"/*."$ext"` if there are files you don't want to rename with different extensions.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the number of digits the index has? I would like to be able to use this script for a folder which contains, for instance, 7 files, 24 files, 114 file, 1000 files or even more. Can printf padding do that? I tryed to do something like `printf '%0$(nr_of_files)d $id'` but it does not seem to work

Comment: @Polb: You don't want the number of files, but the length of the number of  files. Use `${#var}` to get the length of a variable's value.

Comment: Now I understand that what I said is wrong, I need the lenght of the number of files. But still, is there any way to specify something else than an explicit number in `printf`function? I want to insert the variable which holds the number of files instead of the constant value 4. Like `printf '%0$(variable)d $id'`. So my script should keep a constant number of character for the renamed files, in any directory.

Comment: @Polb: Yes, just use `printf "%0${#number_of_files}d" $id`. Parameter expansion doesn't work in single quotes, you need double quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted my script to do.

Comment: What would be wrong with `ls *.jpg | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$(printf basename_%04d.txt $n)"; done` ?

Comment: @FrankN: It doesn't work for `$'a\nb.jpg'` or `' file.jpg'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script, which works only on files, sorts them and renames them with numbers of right length (beginning with zeroes)

```
#!/bin/bash
dots=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f |wc -l|sed "s/./\./g"`
zeroes=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f |wc -l|sed "s/./0/g"`
(
    echo "x=0;zeroes=${zeroes};"
    find  -maxdepth 1 -type f  |sort |sed 's/.*/echo "mv \0 file${zeroes}$((x++)).txt"/'
)|bash|sed "s/\(file\)0*\(${dots}\.txt\)/\1\2/"
```

The scripts just types some `mv something file0012.txt` commands, so you either pipe that to bash, or add `|bash` to the end of the last line

Be also aware, that running such script more times on the same directory (after some modifications - maybe if you add file000000.txt) may result to garbage, as it would try to move files file12.txt to file13.txt possibly overwriting some of them on the way