# How to rename or define multiple files - gstreamer

Tags: rename, prefix

I'm a beginner with raspbian, and trying to do some time lapse.

My camera upload with ftp directly to the Raspberry pi, in file format like this:

```
192.168.1.140_01_20160118205122254_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.140_01_20160118205222260_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.140_01_20160118205322262_TIMING.jpg
```

This is every minute upload from my ip camera.

I'm using gstreamer to do the time lapse, but I don't know how I can specify the files?

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="192.168.1.140???.jpg" ! image/jpeg, framerate=12/1 ! \
decodebin ! video/x-raw, width=1296, height=976 ! progressreport name=progress ! \
omxh264enc target-bitrate=15000000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264, profile=high ! \
h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

Would it be possible to keep the original output from camera, and what should the suffix be? 192.168.1.140_01_???.jpg?

Would it be better, to rename the output, to something else like timelapse0000.jpg timelapse0001.jpg and so on? Then I could use timelapse_%04d.jpg

In this case how can I do this?

I'm pretty much lost here, so I hope to get some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Select multiple files in a folder. For this press and hold down the CTRL key while you are clicking files.
After you select the files, press F2.
Type the new name, and then press ENTER.

Comment: Hi Fred... Sorry if I'm unclear - it's something I want to execute from a ssh promt directly, later add to a script and setup a cronjob to do it daily

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be best to rename the output to sequentially numbered files so that you can easily input them to gstreamer. You can use a bash script to do this as shown here - [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers)

Comment: Hello jfoytik... Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

This one worked perfect:
ls *.jpg| awk 'BEGIN{ a=0 }{ printf "mv %s timelapse%04d.jpg\n", $0, a++ }' | bash