# How rename multiple files numerical order 1, 2, or 3 digit to be 4 digit in terminal command?

Tags: linux

I want rename multiple file like this:

```
qwsas_1.jpg     >> 0001.jpg
2wase_2.jpg     >> 0002.jpg
swaq2_3.jpg     >> 0003.jpg
qweei_14.jpg    >> 0004.jpg
dadaS_23.jpg    >> 0005.jpg
aswee_35.jpg    >> 0006.jpg
```

I use this command:

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
  mv -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers)

But result:

```
qwsas_1.jpg     >> 0001.jpg
qweei_14.jpg    >> 0002.jpg
2wase_2.jpg     >> 0003.jpg
dadaS_23.jpg    >> 0004.jpg
swaq2_3.jpg     >> 0005.jpg
aswee_35.jpg    >> 0006.jpg
```

What should I do with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your files by their number part before looping through and renaming them:

```
a=1
while read -r filename; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
  mv -- "$filename" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done < <(ls *.jpg | sort -t_ -k2n)
```

Sample run:

```
renaming qwsas_1.jpg 0001.jpg
renaming 2wase_2.jpg 0002.jpg
renaming swaq2_3.jpg 0003.jpg
renaming qweei_14.jpg 0004.jpg
renaming dadaS_23.jpg 0005.jpg
renaming aswee_35.jpg 0006.jpg
```

Comment: Thank for your answered. I've tried, but it appears an error like this: line 6: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory. Though that would rename the files still exist