# Interweave contents of two directories into a new directory

Tags: bash

I have two directories with sequential content (i.e., the contents' filenames are 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg, and so on up to a maximum of 1000 files). I want to merge them into a new directory in alternating order like so:

```
Dir1
├── 001.jpg
├── 002.jpg
├── 003.jpg
└── 004.jpg
Dir2
├── 002.jpg
├── 003.jpg
├── 004.jpg
└── 005.jpg

OutputDir
├── 001.jpg (001.jpg from Dir1)
├── 002.jpg (002.jpg from Dir2)
├── 003.jpg (002.jpg from Dir1)
├── 004.jpg (003.jpg from Dir2)
├── 005.jpg (003.jpg from Dir1)
├── 006.jpg (004.jpg from Dir2)
├── 007.jpg (004.jpg from Dir1)
└── 008.jpg (005.jpg from Dir2)
```

This is what I have but it relies on both dirs having the same names:

```
cp Dir1/* OutputDir/
cp --backup=existing --suffix=.2 Dir2/* OutputDir/
cd OutputDir
# next line from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.jpg"; done
```

I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't rely on the file names of both directories to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
#! /bin/bash
a=(Dir1/*)
b=(Dir2/*)
for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};++i)); do
  mv "${a[i]}" "OutputDir/$(printf '%03d.jpg' "$((2*i+1))")"
  mv "${b[i]}" "OutputDir/$(printf '%03d.jpg' "$((2*i+2))")"
done
```

It does assume the same number of files in Dir1 and Dir2, but your example implies that's true.

Comment: You may want to remove the *command substitution* with `ls` entirely and just allow *globbing* to fill the arrays. But, both you and ghoti get the vote for nearly simultaneous answers `:)` I was still puzzling over the logic of which file gets the next sequential number logic (or lack thereof).

Comment: Thanks very much. Done.

Comment: I forgot to indicate but yes both directories have the same number of files.

Comment: @RobinAnupol No problem. Note I added quotes iaw best practice. They're important if the filenames contain characters the shell would reinterpret.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two input directories have the same number of files in each, you might be able to simply step through array indices, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=(Dir1/*.jpg)
b=(Dir2/*.jpg)
n=1

for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
    mv "${a[$i]}" "OutputDir/$( printf '%03d' $n ).jpg"
    ((n++))
    mv "${b[$i]}" "OutputDir/$( printf '%03d' $n ).jpg"
    ((n++))
done
```

If there's the possibility they'll have different numbers of files, you'll need to define the behaviour for that and write something to handle it. Perhaps this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=(Dir1/*.jpg)
b=(Dir2/*.jpg)

if [[ ${#a[@]} -gt ${#b[@]} ]]; then
        c=( ${!a[@]} )
else
        c=( ${!b[@]} )
fi

n=1

for i in "${c[@]}"; do
    echo "i=$i"
    [[ -f "${a[$i]}" ]] &&
      mv -v "${a[$i]}" "OutputDir/$( printf '%03d' $n ).jpg" && ((n++))
    [[ -f "${b[$i]}" ]] &&
      mv -v "${b[$i]}" "OutputDir/$( printf '%03d' $n ).jpg" && ((n++))
done
```

With this solution, if one directory has more files than the other, its files should be appended sequentially to OutputDir following the same counter. Note that `((n++))` only executes if a move is successful, which should insure that your output files are sequential without breaks.

The dependency here is that array indices must be sequential, without breaks.

Comment: Icing on the cake would be `((n >= 1000)) && break` `:)`

Comment: If I could vote twice -- it would be worth twice that. Like I commented with Gene, when you both answered, I was still trying to figure out how to sequence which file got which number. Good job `:)`