# Rename files with consecutive numbers, keeping the original filename

Tags: bash, file, rename

I got a bunch of mp3 files with random names and numbers like:

- 01_fileabc.mp3
- 01.filecdc.mp3
- fileabc.mp3
- 929-audio.mp3

For sorting purposes, I need to add a sequential number in front of the file name like:

- 001_01_fileabc.mp3
- 002_01.filecdc.mp3
- 003_fileabc.mp3
- 004_929-audio.mp3

I checked some of the solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1). One of the first solutions worked kind of but replaced the filename instead of adding to it.

```
num=0; for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(printf '%04d' $num).${i#*.}"; ((num++)); done
```

How can I modify this command to add to the filename instead?
I am sorry, but whatever I try I can't find a solution myself here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `${i#*.}` (which stands for "Remove from $i from the left up to the first dot) with `$i`, which is the original name of the file (I'd probably use `$filename`, `$oldfile`, or at least `$f` instead of `$i` as the variable's name).

You can also replace the `.` before it with `_`, otherwise the files will be named

```
0001.01_fileabc.mp3
```

etc.

Comment: ...and replace the glob `*` with `*.mp3` to rename only the files with a `.mp3` file extension. Complete revised command as follows: `num=1; for filename in *.mp3; do mv "$filename" "$(printf '%04d' $num)_$filename"; ((num++)); done`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** As [RobC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc) commented about this answer, existing whitespace or newline characters can cause problems listing files because of using `ls` command with bash arrays. So the above code can be improved in this way

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for file in *.mp3; do
    i=$((i+1))
    mv "$file" "$(printf "%03d_%s" "$i" "$file")"
done
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** You can try this code in a bash script. Remember to make it executable with
`$ chmod +x script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
contents_dir=($(ls *.mp3))
for file in ${!contents_dir[*]}; do
    new=$(awk -v i="$file" -v cd="${contents_dir[$file]}" 'BEGIN {printf("%03d_%s", i+1, cd)}')
mv ${contents_dir[$file]} $new
done
```

It will add a consecutive 0-leaded tree digits number as you wanted to all mp3 files found in the dir where the script is executed.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I really need to find a place on how to learn bash.

Comment: Whilst this solution works given the filenames in the OP, it will fail if a filename contains a space or newline character. Further info regarding _"Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls"_ can be found [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this …

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 01.filecdc.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 01_fileabc.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 929-audio.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 fileabc.mp3

$ t=0
$ for i in *mp3
> do
>     # Use the seq command to get a formatted zero filled string.
>     prefix=$(seq -f "%04g" $t $t)
>
>     # Move $i to new file name.
>     mv $i ${prefix}_${i}
>
>     # Increment our counter, t.
>     t=$(expr $t + 1)
> done


$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 0000_01.filecdc.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 0001_01_fileabc.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 0002_929-audio.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 plankton None 5 Nov  4 13:35 0003_fileabc.mp3
```