# Rename multiple files with a sequence of numbers in cmd and batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

This is my first question in this beautiful website.
As you probably read in the title I would like to rename a variable number of files, with a sequence of numbers in cmd and a batch file, the sequence is increasing and it is like this (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...).
For example:

*Test.txt* it should become *1.txt*

*Another.txt* should become *2.txt*

And so on, all automatically.

My idea was to set up a variable like `set /a number=1` and add +1 like this `set number="%number%+1"` to it through a loop and rename each time, but it isn't possible since when I rename files with `ren`
command it renames all at once.

Can anyone help me providing a cmd and a batch file version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really have not provided a [mcve] of your code. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, AleP _C.P. Questions without code should go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: If you're using a looping mechanism, for your incrementing, you must already know that a loop would iterate the files one at a time, not 'all at once'. What you need to look into is a [tag:for-loop], and there are tens of tousands of examples of those under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag alone! Please use the search facility and adapt some code, before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63942028/edit) to bring it on topic.

Comment: I guess you're using `ren *.* %number%.*`, right?

Comment: Sorry for not providing all this important informations, thanks for all, this is my first question and I never wrote anything in this website. I will carefully read all the documentation.

Comment: My preferred way of doing is this to install `git` and the use [this bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10780250/1176573) to rename. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
set /a Index=1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%i in (*.txt) do ( 
    rename "%%i" "!Index!.txt"
    set /a Index+=1
)
```

Create a batch file with above code and run it in folder where your .txt files are available.

If you want to append "0" to make it 2 digits. you can try adding if else statement as below.

```
set /a Index=1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%i in (*.txt) do ( 
    rem if number is less than 10, append 9 to file name
    if !Index! lss 10 (
        rename "%%i" 0"!Index!.txt"
    ) else (
        rename "%%i" "!Index!.txt"
    )
    
    set /a Index+=1
)
```

Comment: Here, output comes as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12....'
Can it be 01,02,03,04,05... in 2 digits?'

Comment: @foodiepanda Unfortunately, I was not active here for while. Not sure if you still want to make it 2 digits number or not. I have updated my answer in case if you still need it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating answer, I do not need it now, but future visitors could'