# Update numbers in filenames

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I have a set of filenames which are ordered numerically like:

```
13B12363_1B1_0.png
13B12363_1B1_1.png
13B12363_1B1_2.png
13B12363_1B1_3.png
13B12363_1B1_4.png
13B12363_1B1_5.png
13B12363_1B1_6.png
13B12363_1B1_7.png
13B12363_1B1_8.png
13B12363_1B1_9.png
13B12363_1B1_10.png
[...]
13B12363_1B1_495.png
13B12363_1B1_496.png
13B12363_1B1_497.png
13B12363_1B1_498.png
13B12363_1B1_499.png
```

After some postprocessing, I removed some files and I would like to update the ordering number and replace the actual number by its new position. Looking at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers) I end up doing something like:

(1) `ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -i $f ${f%%[0-9]+.png}_$n.png; done`

However, this command do not recognize the "ordering number + png" and just append the new number at the end of the filename. Something like `13B12363_1B1_10.png_9.png`

On the other hand, if I do:

(2) `ls -v * | cat -n | while read n f; do mv $f ${f%.*}_$n.png; done`

The ordering number is added without issues. Like `13B12363_1B1_10_9.png`

So, for (1) it seems I am not specifying the `digit` correctly but I am not able to find the correct syntax. So far I tried `[0-9]`, `[0-9]+`, `[[:digits:]]` and `[[:digits:]]+`. Which should be the proper one?

Additionally, in (2) I am wondering how I should specify `rename` (CentOS version) to remove the numbers between the second and the third underscore. Here I have to say that I have some filenames like `20B12363_22_10_9.png`, so I should somehow specify **second** and **third** underscore.

Comment: Is the order important? I mean, is that the reason you used `-v`on ls? Or any other order will do as long as the gaps are filled?

Comment: @Julio, yes, the order is important

Comment: Thanks. I understand than your input is controlled... Can your file names have new lines or quotes?

Comment: Nope, the structure of the filenames would be `[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+_[aA-zZ|0-9]+_[0-9]+.png`.  In another example, the files have some extra numbers in between like: `[0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+_[aA-zZ|0-9]+((_[0-9]+_)*n)[0-9]+.png` but I guess this second case would be easily adapted

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash's built-in Basic Regex Engine and a `null` delimited list of files.

Tested with sample

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prename=$1

# Bash setting to return empty result if no match found
shopt -s nullglob

# Create a temporary directory to prevent file rename collisions
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1

# Add a trap to remove the temporary directory on EXIT
trap 'rmdir -- "$tmpdir"'  EXIT

# Initialize file counter
n=0

# Generate null delimited list of files
printf -- %s\\0 "${prename}_"*'.png' |

# Sort the null delimited list on 3rd field numeric order with _ separator
sort --zero-terminated --field-separator=_ --key=3n |

# Iterate the null delimited list
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  
  # If Bash Regex match the file name AND
  # file has a different sequence number

  if [[ "$f" =~ (.*)_([0-9]+)\.png$ ]] && [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} -ne $n ]]; then

    # Use captured Regex match group 1 to rename file with incrementing counter
    # and move it to the temporary folder to prevent rename collision with
    # existing file
    echo mv -- "$f" "$tmpdir/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$((n)).png"
  fi

  # Increment file counter
  n=$((n+1))
done

# Move back the renamed files in place
mv --no-clobber -- "$tmpdir/*" ./

# $tempdir removal is automatic on EXIT
# If something goes wrong, some files remain in it and it is not deleted
# so these can be dealt with manually
```

Remove the `echo`  if the result matches your expectations.

Output from the sample

```sh
mv -- 13B12363_1B1_495.png /tmp/tmp.O2HmbyD7d5/13B12363_1B1_11.png
mv -- 13B12363_1B1_496.png /tmp/tmp.O2HmbyD7d5/13B12363_1B1_12.png
mv -- 13B12363_1B1_497.png /tmp/tmp.O2HmbyD7d5/13B12363_1B1_13.png
mv -- 13B12363_1B1_498.png /tmp/tmp.O2HmbyD7d5/13B12363_1B1_14.png
mv -- 13B12363_1B1_499.png /tmp/tmp.O2HmbyD7d5/13B12363_1B1_15.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It does exactly what is neeced, however, I have to loop through different filenames prenames in the same folder (like 13B12363_1B1, 14B12245_1A, etc), I guess I should add a `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '$prename_*.png' |` before the `printf -- %s\\0 * |` command, right?

Comment: @Tato14 Either change the printf -- %s\\n's argument to "${prename}_"*'.png' or replace the printf entirely with a find ... -print0 The -print0 option of find just generates a null delimited list. – Léa Gris 23 secs ago

Answer (score 2):

[Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

`read` interprets \ and splits on IFS. [bashfaq how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

In `${f%%replacement}` expansion the replacement is not regex, but globulation. Rules differ. `+` means literally `+`.

You could `shopt -o extglob` and then `${f%%+([0-9]).png}`. Or write a loop. Or match the `_` too and do `f=${f%%.png}; f="${f%_[0-9]*}_"`.

Or something along (untested):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '13B12363_1B1_*.png' |
sort -t_ -n -k3 |
sed 's/\(.*\)[0-9]+\.png$/&\t\1/' |
{
    n=1;
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r from to; do
       echo mv "$from" "$to$((n++)).png";
    done;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fot the `ls` advice. (1)Looking at your suggestions I rebuild the command like:
`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '13B12363_1B1_*.png' | sort -t _ -n -k3 | cat -n | while read n f; do echo mv $f ${f%_[0-9]*}_$n.png; done`
This works nicely, however, I am not quite sure if this will work with the `20B12363_22_10_9.png` example.

(2)`shopt -o extglob` throws an error.

(3)`while` command does not keep the filename and just replace filename by the proper number like: `mv ./13B12363_1B1_499.png 482.png`

Comment: Since I want 0-based rename: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "13B12363_1B1*.png" | sort -t _ -n -k3 | cat -n | while read n f; do echo mv $f ${f%_[0-9]*}_$((n-1)).png; done; done`

Comment: Pay attention to rename collision when renumbering sequences (I found out I needed to in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, with perl:

```
perl -e 'while(<@ARGV>){$o=$_;s/\d+(?=\D*$)/$i++.".renamed"/e;die if -e $_;rename $o,$_}while(<*.renamed>){$o=$_;s/\.renamed$//;die if -e $_;rename $o,$_}' $(ls -v|sed -E "s/$|^/'/g"|paste -sd ' ' -)
```

This solution should avoid rename collisions by: first renaming files adding extra ".renamed" extension. And then removing the ".renamed" extension as the last step. Also, There are checks to detect rename collision.

Anyways, **please backup your data before trying :)**

---

The perl script unrolled and explained:

```
while(<@ARGV>){ # loop through arguments. 
                # filenames are passed to "$_" variable
    
    # save old file name
    $o=$_;

    # if not using variable, regex replacement (s///) uses topic variable ($_)
    # e flag ==> evals the replacement
    s/\d+(?=\D*$)/$i++.".renamed"/e;  # works on $_

    # Detect rename collision
    die if -e $_;

    rename $o,$_
}
while(<*.renamed>){
    $o=$_;
    s/\.renamed$//; # remove .renamed extension
    die if -e $_;
    rename $o,$_
}
```

The regex:

```
\d+       # one number or more
(?=\D*$)  # followed by 0 or more non-numbers and end of string
```

Comment: Pay attention to rename collision when renumbering

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris, I finally reverted to my original version, that used `ls -v`. That should avoid rename collision according to OP specs.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)