# how to change multiple folder names at once on linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a set of folders named

```
-> section 1, section 2, section 3, ... , section 12
```

How do I change them to read

```
-> video 1, video 2 ..., video 12
```

on a linux platform?

I tried:

```sh
mv section* video*
```

But no love

Comment: may need list with order then mv with new name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers if you don't have sequential folders, list into an array and remove the `section` from the string and concat video on it

Comment: how? I do have sequential folders.

Comment: You could use `find` to *find* each file you want to rename. Then using any linux/bash tool to replace `section` with `video`.

Comment: Thanks but these comments aren't really helpful.  The problem is I have a space followed by a number.  I want to keep the space and the number and just change the word section to video.  A sample of how to do this would be really helpful. (I've been using linux for 3 days)

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I believe ssh  (is that a shell?) whoops, when I do echo $SHELL i get /bin/bash

Comment: Then you should add the [tag:bash]-tag to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`${target/search/replace}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script) [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace the first occurrence of a pattern within a given string.

Combine that with [`find -exec`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) to [rename the folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154818/how-to-integrate-mv-command-after-find-command).

```sh
find . -type d -iname 'section*' -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/section/video}"' {} \;
```

- [`find .`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html): Find in **the current directory**
- `-type d`: Only search for folders (use `-type f` for **f**iles)
- `-iname 'section*'`: Search pattern
- `-maxdepth 1`: Restrict find from going deep
- `-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/section/video}"' {} \;`

  - `-exec` run the following command for each path found
  - pass `{}` (path found by `find`) as argument so we can use `$0`
  - [`mv`](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html)`"$0" "${0/section/video}"`

    - Move the file/folder from the current position
    - To the new position where we use the above mentioned bash syntax to replace `section` with `video`

Example:

- **Navigate to the desired folder**
  <sup>This answer assumes the *search* and *replace* pattern only appear **once** in the path</sup>

```
$ cd /tmp/test
$
$
$ rm -rf *
$ mkdir section\ 1 section\ 2 section\ 35
$
$
$ find .
.
./section 1
./section 35
./section 2
$
$ find . -type d -iname 'section*' `-maxdepth 1` -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/section/video}"' {} \;
$
$ find .
.
./video 2
./video 1
./video 35
$
$
```

#### Use with caution

Comment: this is great.  Can you provide a reference to the documentation?

Comment: Glad it helped. Added some more links. If I missed any, let me know.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. Changed my answer to give an example renaming folders. Had some issues with quoting and an error. Solved by using `-maxdepth 1` to prevent `find` from searching for folders that we've already renamed. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: looks good.  Thanks a lot for coming back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice shell script which can perform batch renaming: [vimv](https://github.com/thameera/vimv).

*Warning*: before use, please read carefully the README, especially the "Gotchas" section at the end.

It takes a list of files as parameters (or defaults to the files of the current directory) and opens your favourite editor with a temporary file where each line is one of the file paths you gave. Then you just have to modify any path in order to move or rename it.

The advantage is that you can perform very complex renamings, depending on the editor you are using.

In your case, you could do the following:

```
$ ls
'section 1'  'section 10'  'section 11'  'section 12'  'section 2'  'section 3'  'section 4'  'section 5'  'section 6'  'section 7'  'section 8'  'section 9'
$ vimv section*
[Inside Vim editor...] :%s/section/video
[Inside Vim editor...] :wq
12 files renamed.
$ ls
'video 1'  'video 10'  'video 11'  'video 12'  'video 2'  'video 3'  'video 4'  'video 5'  'video 6'  'video 7'  'video 8'  'video 9'
```