# rename multiple files in linux with number plus a constant

Tags: linux, renaming

I want to rename all the files in a folder with numbers in their names, like

- Solution_01.vtu
- Solution_02.vtu
- Solution_03.vtu
  ...

to be

- Solution_201.vtu
- Solution_202.vtu
- Solution_203.vtu
  ...

where the additional constant (here 200) can be specified.

I've tried something along the lines of that suggested in [Renaming a set of files to 001, 002, ... on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880467/renaming-a-set-of-files-to-001-002-on-linux)

```
i=200; temp=$(mktemp -p .); for file in solution_*.vtu 
do 
mv "$file" $temp; 
mv $temp $(printf "solution_%0.3d.vtu" $i) 
i = $((i+1)) 
done
```

but this doesn't work for me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Share some code you tried at this point, and explain on what you are stuck because we will not do the whole script for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command:

```
 find . -printf 'mv %f %f\n' | grep -v '\. \.' | sed 's/u Solution_/u Solution_2/g' | while read -r i ; do $i ; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this isn't quite what I was looking for as this just appends an extra 2. I.e. if I have Solution_200.vtu Solution_201.vtu I will get Solution_2200.vtu Solution_2201.vtu instead of Solution_400.vtu, Solution_401.vtu which is what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ruby on your Linux machine :

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'

pattern = ARGV[0] || "*.vtu"
offset  = (ARGV[1] || 200).to_i

Dir[pattern].each do |file|
  id = file[/\d+/]
  if id then
    new_id = id.to_i + offset
    new_file = file.sub(/\d+/, new_id.to_s)
    puts "#{file} -> #{new_file}"
    ## UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT TO MOVE FILES:
    # FileUtils.mv file, new_file
  end
end
```

You can use it like this :

```
./rename_with_integer_offset.rb "*.vtu" 200
# solution_201.vtu -> solution_401.vtu
# solution_202.vtu -> solution_402.vtu
```