# How to copy files with the same name in different source dir and rename in destination dir?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have a list of files in following structure:

```
 A/abc.zip
 B/abc.zip
 C/abc.zip
```

I want to use copy command to copy them:

```
$ cp */abc.zip ~/dest/
```

This seems to replace the file every time, how can I copy these files properly with Linux bash?

Say if I want to rename it to be `dest/A-abc.zip`, `dest/B-abc.zip`, `dest/C-abc.zip`?

Comment: if you use the --parents flag it should copy the folder paths to all of the abc.zip into dest

Comment: This question deals with the problem of copying and renaming in one command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115813/how-to-rename-files-while-copying

Comment: "I want to use the copy command" -- should we take this to mean you wouldn't accept any answer that *didn't*  use `cp`? If not, how *should* we understand that line to reflect your  intent?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, ideally cp or basic bash cmd, as I use an old cygwin, it does not support some advanced command.

Comment: If you have `rsync`, then you can use the `-R` option.

Comment: You should show your code so folks know where you are having trouble. All the parts of this question have been asked and answered previously. Possible duplicate of [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211595/608639), [Renaming a set of files to 001, 002, … on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880467/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *need* to put everything in the same path, you could maintain the structure using `--parent` :

```
$ cp --parent */abc.zip ~/dest

$ tree ~/dest
~/dest
├── 1
│   └── abc.zip
├── 2
│   └── abc.zip
└── 3
    └── abc.zip
```