# Rename multiple files, but only delete part of the filename

Tags: python, linux, bash

I tried the ('mv', 'sed') command's in Linux .
I have more than one file I want to delete the last character of the file like this

Before

```
natural1_dd-aa.txt
natural2_dd-aa.txt
natural3_dd-aa.txt
```

I want to delete `('_dd-aa')`

After

```
natural1.txt
natural2.txt
natural3.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211595/608639), [Renaming a set of files to 001, 002, … on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880467/608639), [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428109/608639), [How to remove last n characters from a string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27658675/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

These days, I'm using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this kind of problem.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(".").glob("*.txt"):
    path.rename(path.with_name(path.stem.partition("_dd-aa")[0] + path.suffix))
```

(**Update**: This answer was appropriate prior to the removal of the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag when the question was edited. It's no longer relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

Tentative to answer in case there are fundamental issues with this, but:

```
find . -name \*_dd-aa\* | while read filename
do
    mv "$filename" "$(echo $filename | sed 's/_dd-aa//g')"
done
```

...seems to work as requested.

### Method

1. Find all files that contain `_dd-aa`
2. Obtain the new filename by removing the `_dd-aa` part
3. Use `mv` to rename the file

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for that reference.

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
ls *dd-aa* | sed 's/\(.*\)_dd-aa\(.txt\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh
```

List only those files with the pattern(`*dd-aa*`). Using `sed`, prepare the mv command by taking 1st part before the pattern (`_dd-aa`) and the 2nd part after the pattern. And pass it on to a shell.

Comment: Downvoted because [you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).